# Optimization for opcode EXTCODEHASH

Tags: solidity, eip

I have re edited the questions, simplified and organized the main ones.

Just to determine whether an address is a contract, whether it has eth or not, the general method is

```
keccak256(add.code) == keccak256(bytes(" "));
add.code.length ==0;
```

When the code is very long, the gas will be very high. To save gas, codehash should be used

```
add.codehash == 0;
```

But when I specifically use and understand codehash, An address is not a contract. When there is no eth, the codehash is 0x. An address is not a contract. When there is eth, the codehash is keccak256(bytes(" ")).

```
add.code=0;
add.codehash =！ 0;
add.codehash ==keccak256(bytes(" "));
```

In actual applications, the contract has not been created yet, but it is normal to have eth. Therefore, for the sake of security, codehash is not used in the end, but other methods are used. It completely deviates from the original intention of [eip-1052](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1052) to save gas, making EXTCODEHASH a bit meaningless.

https://ethereum-magicians.org/t/eip-7637-extcodehash-optimize/18946

Comment: In order to have more changes you should include a concrete use case. Why do you need that change? How will it affect clients implementation? What will happen to existing contracts that use the old behavior?

Comment: I have re edited the questions, simplified and organized the main ones. @Ismael

Answer (score 0):

Alternative for Checking if an Address is a Contract

Combining Checks

**Logic:**

An EOA (Externally Owned Account) typically has a code size of zero.
An EOA might accidentally be treated as a contract if it holds ETH, as its codehash won't be zero.
Combining extcodesize and codehash checks significantly improves reliability.

**Example Code:**

```
function isContract(address addr) returns (bool) {
    uint size;
    assembly { size := extcodesize(addr) }
    return size > 0 && addr.codehash != keccak256(bytes(""));
}
```

This function returns true only if the address has a non-zero code size and a code hash that doesn't match the "default" hash of an ETH-holding EOA.

**Note:**

**The combined checks method generally costs slightly more in terms of gas compared to a simple EXTCODEHASH check alone.**

Here's why:

**EXTCODESIZE**:  Calling the EXTCODESIZE opcode itself to get the code size of an address incurs some gas cost.
~ 700

**Additional Logic**: The extra conditional check ( addr.codehash != keccak256(bytes("")) ) in the combined method adds a bit more gas overhead for the evaluation and comparison.
~200

**Assembly**: While using assembly for EXTCODESIZE optimizes slightly, it won't fully negate the added cost compared to  using  EXTCODEHASH  by itself.
SLOAD (~700)

Comment: It seems that we only need to use extcodesize.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we only need to use extcodesize

```
    function isContract(address n_add)public view returns(bool){
        uint size;
        assembly { size := extcodesize(n_add) }
        return size > 0;
    }
```

Comment: May be the given solution may not help due to following reasons:

1. Contracts Under Construction: During deployment, a contract may temporarily have zero code size until the transaction finalizes.


2. Self-Destructed Contracts: Contracts with a SELFDESTRUCT function can intentionally remove their code, resulting in a size of zero.


3. Also, the introduction of Account Abstraction(AA) after the Dencun upgrade will make it more complex to find if the account is CA or EOA as EOA will also act like a Smart Account.

Comment: I'm just using it to determine if the contract for create2 has been created.